# restrict the Standard buttons on a standard page to be on top only

Tags: standard-objects, detail-page, standardlayout

Was wondering if there is a way to show the button on a standard page to be available only on the top of the page instead of displaying both and top and bottom of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you tagging your question with apex and visualforce when you speak about standard pages only? In short, this is not possible on standard pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged this question to `visualforce` you can do this with custom page as below. For standard pages I do not think it is possible.

I believe you are using `<apex:pageBlockButtons>` for buttons. There is a `location` attribute present in it. As per Salesforce documentation the description for this attribute is -- *The area of the page block where the buttons should be rendered. Possible values include "top", "bottom", or "both". If not specified, this value defaults to "both".*

You have to use `top` to show buttons only on top.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```